# Could I pick the best model based on the bias-variance tradeoff?

Tags: model-selection, bias-variance-tradeoff

Usually would I pick the best performing model according to accuracy, or another evaluation method, on the validation dataset.

But is this viable to chose the best model according to bias-variance tradeoff between the training and validation datasets, or are other measurements necessary?

Comment: You don’t know the actual bias or variance in real-life scenarios.

Comment: What exactly do you have in mind? Looking at something with the bias and variance tells me that you're interested in mean squared error, which is a reasonable evaluation metric.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So, how do you propose to trade off bias against variance? I.e., what trade-off do you consider optimal and why?

Comment: In my case had I trained a binary classifier (Logistic regression) with grid search and cross validation of different parameters for regularization. The model overfitted  based on training and validation accuracy, which poked my interest for a simpler model based around bias-variance tradeoff.

Comment: What I'm wondering is; can I pick a model based on the bias-variance trade of. 
For instance, say I'd traine n knn classifiers, gradually increasing in complexity. Insted of picking the model with the least error rate on the validation set, could I pick the model with the least error rate from training and validation combined in some way?

Comment: However do I know think this question contradicts itself since the validation set is meant to find the sweet spot between the two I guess.